# Imagemagick: Create 1 image out of 3 with luminance/overlay mask

Tags: imagemagick

I want to generate an image out of 3 images. One of these images is the background, one the shape mask and one the color of the shape.

Here are the images:

shape.png
[image: shape.png]
(transparent background, white circle in the middle and black circle inside and gray circle inside the black one)

shapecolor.png
[image: shapecolor.png]

background.png
[image: background.png]

The background.png should be the overall background. On top of that is the shape and all white parts (and also the white in the gray parts) should be in the color of shapecolor.png

I used simple mono color images to make it easier but I use some textures in reality ^^

I have no idea how to solve this problem in Imagemagick, the tool is very powerful and the documentation is not so easy to understand. Tried to solve this for 3h, but did not get the result, which should look like this: 
[image]

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it in Imagemagick. In the second line, extract the alpha channel from omg.png and save it in an mpr: in-memory image and then delete the clone. Then I use the mpr: image later in the last step.

```
convert red.png img.png \
\( +clone -alpha extract -write mpr:alpha +delete \) \
-compose multiply -composite \
green.png +swap mpr:alpha -compose over -composite \
result.png
```

[image]